# php mail not sending from contact form

Tags: php, forms, email, post

I have put together a form with validation with help from this tutorial: http://www.w3resource.com/php/form/php-form-validation.php

I am hoping somebody can point out where I have gone wrong? As my validation works, I get a thankyou message but no mail comes through to my inbox :(

```
<?php        
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {        
    //checking name        
    if(empty($_POST['full_name']))        
    $msg_name = "*";        
    $name_subject = $_POST['full_name'];        
    //check phone number        
    if(empty($_POST['Phone_Num']))        
    $msg_Phone = "*";        
    $email_subject = $_POST['Phone_Num'];        
    //check email        
    if(empty($_POST['email_addr']))        
    $msg_email = "*";        
    $email_subject = $_POST['email_addr'];        
    $email_pattern = '/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/';        
    preg_match($email_pattern, $email_subject, $email_matches);        
    if(!$email_matches[0])        
    $msg2_email = "Please enter a valid email address";
}           
// validation complete         
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){        
    if($msg_name=="" && $msg2_name=="" && $msg_email=="" && $msg2_email=="" &&         $msg2_Message=="")        
    $msg_success = "Thankyou for your enquiry";        
    //send mail           
    $to = "someone@email.com";          
    $subject = "Data collected thorugh from";          
    $message = "<p>".$_POST["full_name"]."</p><p>".$_POST["Phone_Num"]."        </p><p>".$_POST["email_addr"]."</p><p>".$_POST["Message"]."</p>";
    $from = "someone@email.com";          
    mail($to,$subject,$message);          
}        
?>
```

Comment: Have you done **ANY** debugging yourself? Checked the return value of `mail()` for failure? Check your mail server's logs to see what happened to the mail once php handed it over? Checked your spam folder in case the message got trashed?

Comment: where you are running this code local/server ...If it is in server check SMTP settings

Comment: Hello! thankyou for replying, I havent.. this is my first form with validation I am quite new to php. My server is 123 reg. I used the live chat to talk to them about this and they said: First of all make sure your code use an 123-reg email address hosted on your primary domain name for the hosting. (which I am)

Daniel: (12:03): And also that the script uses SMTP authentication. (although i am not sure what this is)

Answer (score 0):

The PHP mail() function does not allow for sending email through SMTP with authentification. If you want do this, there is a PEAR package.

[This article](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm) gives some explanation.